# QSortFIlterProxyModel не отображаются данные вставленной строки

Tags: c++, qt, tableview, qabstracttablemodel

у меня есть следующая задача.
Для столбцов строк отмеченных чекбоксами нужно посчитать среднее арифметическое и добавить в таблицу. Для QAbstractListModel все работает корректно. Но при переходе на QSortFilterProxyModel получается следующий результат
[image: результат вставки строк]

Привожу часть кода

```
int TableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
        return QSortFilterProxyModel::rowCount() + values.count();
}     
void TableModel::populate(QList<TableData> newValues)
{
        this->beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0);
            this->values= newValues;
        endInsertRows();
}

QVariant TableModel::data( const QModelIndex &index, int role ) const
{
   ...
   value = QSortFilterProxyModel::data(index, role);
   if (index.row()>2) value = this->values.at(index.row()-3).getValueByIndex(index.column());
   return value;     
   ...
}
```

Чего я не учитываю или в чем ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прокси-модели используют индексы модели источника для получения своих индексов с помощью метода `QAbstractProxyModel::mapToSource`. В итоге если в прокси-модели индексов больше чем в модели источнике, то индексы не присутствующие в модели-источнике будут вести себя некорректно.

Для корректной работы Вам нужно переопределить методы:

```
QModelIndex TableModel::mapToSource(const QModelIndex& proxyIndex) const
{
    if (proxyIndex.row() >= sourceModel()->rowCount()) {
        return createIndex(proxyIndex.row(), proxyIndex.column());
    }
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource(proxyIndex);
}

QModelIndex TableModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    if (row >=  sourceModel()->rowCount()) {
        return createIndex(row, column);
    }
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::index(row, column, parent);
}

Qt::ItemFlags TableModel::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (index.row() >= sourceModel()->rowCount()) {
        return Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemNeverHasChildren;
    }
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::flags(index);
}
```

Помимо этого нужно заметить, что помимо `mapToSource` `QSortFilterProxyModel` использует скрытую от пользователя функцию `index_to_iterator` для ускорения многих операций. Она работает на основе `internalPointer`-а индекса, который у нас для `row >= sourceModel()->rowCount()` равен `nullptr`. (Мы использовали [`QAbstractItemModel::createIndex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#createIndex)). По этой причине нам нужно переопределить методы, которые могут использовать данную функцию на наших добавочных индексах (Как правило в других прокси-моделях их тоже необходимо переопределять, но по другим причинам):

```
QModelIndex TableModel::parent(const QModelIndex& child) const
{
    return QModelIndex(); //Мы знаем, что работаем с таблицей
}

QModelIndex TableModel::sibling(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& idx) const
{
    if (row >= sourceModel()->rowCount()) {
        return createIndex(row, column);
    }
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::sibling(row, column, idx);
}
```

Замечу, что помимо этих мест, `index_to_iterator` неявно вызывается в приватном методе `QSortFilterProxyModelPrivate::needsReorder`, на который мы повлиять не можем, а потому я не могу предсказать насколько корректно будет работать сортировка модели (это я не тестировал). Однако, я бы в любом случае порекомендовал вам использовать `QSortFilterProxyModel` исключительно для вопросов фильтрации и сортировки, а дополнительные строки добавлять через ещё одну прокси-модель наследуемую от `QIdentityProxyModel`.

Обратите внимание, что я предполагал использование таблиц. Для деревьев всё немного сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема тут `QVariant TableModel::data( const QModelIndex &index, int role ) const`, поскольку передаваемый здесь `QModelIndex` принадлежит модели таблицы, а используя `QSortFilterProxyModel` вы уже перемешали все индексы изначальной модели.

Что у вас делает эта штука `value = QSortFilterProxyModel::data(index, role);` честно говоря непонятно

Если я правильно помню, вам надо получить исходный индекс из индекса прокси модели и работать с ним: `QModelIndex sourceIndex = yourProxyModel->mapToSource(index);`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#mapToSource

PS: Это не точно(ц), но в любом случае дебаг решает

Comment: Внутри `QSortFilterProxyModel::data(index, role);` как раз и вызывается `mapToSource`